# telegrambot gives me 'No suggested keys error'

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, telepot

yesterday I tried my bot with a friend, everything was ok until today, when he deleted the chat, now I'm receiving this error:
[image]
Looking online I discovered that this should be an update, is there any way in which I could handle this kind of things? Someone talks about ChatMemberHandler, but I didn't find nothing about that

Comment: Could you add ur code?

Comment: Which part? because variables and comments are in italian and it's 500 lines of code

Comment: I discovered now that my friend deleted the chat with the bot, how can I handle the message I am receiving?

Comment: That might be the error cause if the chat doesnt exists anymore

Comment: @dotheM How can I handle the problem?

Comment: if the chat doesnt exists anymore, you would need to remove the chat from the lists of chats you want the bot to work on i guess. its hard to say without the full error message or code.